# ¿Como acomodar la flecha que indica submenus en una aplicacion de Shiny/R-Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Buenas mi consulta es la siguiente, me gustaria acomodar la flecha que indica que se despliega un menu en shiny pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo y buscando en internet no encuentro algo tan especifico. Me gustaria poder verlo como en el cuadro verde pero me sale como esta en el cuadro rojo. Agraezco cualquier ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo reproducible:

global.R

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
```

ui.R

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.content-wrapper { height: 2000px !important;}'))),

    hr(),

    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                menuItem("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", icon=icon("chart-bar"),
                         menuSubItem("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", tabName = "B", icon = icon("angle-right")),selected=TRUE),

                conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'B'  || input.tabs == 'C'",

                                 fluidRow(column(1),column(10,

                                                           menuItem("CCCCCCCCCCCCC", tabName="C", icon=icon("chart-line"),
                                                                    menuSubItem("DDDDDDDDDDDDDD", tabName = "D", icon = icon("angle-right")))
                                 )))
                                 ),width = 350,hr())

body <- dashboardBody()


dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "Titulo", titleWidth=300),

    sidebar,

    body
)
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
```